# mat daterangepicker loading in cdk-overlay-container div not in my component tree so it is creating problem in shadowDom mode

Tags: angular, angular-material

i am using material dateRangePicker and i enabled shadow Dom Actually material CSS is present in my angular shadow-root component  which is in shadow Dom  ok see in inspection mode  when i opened datepicker it opened Or rendered the datepicker component in cdk-overlay-container which is outside of my shadow-root in inspection mode

so i just want to simply load datepicker under my shadow-root element not  outside in cdk-overlay-container

Comment: check this link:https://www.bbogdanov.dev/post/angular-material-overlay-hack-overlay-container

Comment: yeah i checked it But Not Getting how to implement this for Mat DateRangePicker